# Filtering datatable where sum of grouped column value is not zero

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, filtering

Can we display the data table rows where grouped column value is not zero.
first, I need to group by `sno` and display ungrouped data where amount is not zero.

For example:
I have a data table like below:

[image: input]

need output like this

[image: output]

However I get this with the below code

[image: grouped output]

```
FinalDataTable = table.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(r => new { Col1 = r["sno"]})
                    .Select(g =>{
                            var row = table.NewRow();
                            row["sno"] = g.Key.Col1;
                            row["amount"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("amount"));
                            return row;
                    }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: code? what have you tried?

Comment: `Can we display` - yes, we can :)

Comment: We are happy to help you but we can not do your work for you. You should show us some of your try at least...

Comment: Valid Point. Agreed. Updated my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you want to do is Group by `sno` and then use Where to find those records where the Sum of amount is not zero. Then simply use Select Many to unwrap those groups back into rows.

I think this should do it (I've assumed amount is an `int`)

```
FinalDataTable = table.AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(r => r["sno"])
                        .Where(g => g.Sum(r => (int)r["amount"]) != 0)
                        .SelectMany(r => r)
                        .CopyToDataTable();
```

Here is a live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ixi0aW